# Recursive directory traversal/tree consumes extreme amounts of memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, tree-traversal

I have written a recursive directory traversal method in C# (hosted from an asp.net page).  The code works as I intended (I enumerate a list of shares on a target machine then recurse through the shares and add each file/directory to a TreeView).  Unfortunately this consumes an extreme amount of memory and takes a very long time to run, opening the aspx page causes the Webdev.Webserver ram usage to spike to 800 megabytes, and the Chrome instance viewing the page consumes a whopping 1.5GB of RAM! (running the test code against SMB shares hosted on my local workstation)    I can't even view the page source without chrome hanging.

```
foreach (TreeNode n in FileSelectList.Nodes)
{
    Dir_Node_Recurse(n, hostName);
    //break;
}
```

Uncommenting out the //break; statement results in only the first directory share being processed, and this consumes far less memory.   FileSelectList is an Asp:TreeView.

```
public static void Dir_Node_Recurse(TreeNode node, string hostName)
{
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(String.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}",
                                                            hostName,
                                                            node.ValuePath.ToString()
                                                           ));
        TreeNode tNode;
        foreach (var i in dir.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            tNode = new TreeNode(i.Name.ToString());
            node.ChildNodes.Add(tNode);
            Dir_Node_Recurse(tNode, hostName);
        }

        foreach (var i in dir.EnumerateFiles())
        {
            node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(i.Name.ToString()));
        }
}
```

This appears to cause extreme resource usage because of the large number of TreeNode objects being created.   Should I create my own node type to perhaps minimize memory usage, or is there another technique that would make this usable?

Comment: Any reason why you have to enumerate all the folders up front, rather than waiting for user input - if the user can choose whether to drill into a particular folder, wouldn't this be a good time to look @ the contents of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to get all the nodes? Can you use an on demand approach?

You can also profile the code. You can try pointing the code to a smaller directory and observe it's behavior.

Comment: Well I was going to make methods to process all selected files, this tree has a checkbox on it.   Also I wanted to be able to store the list of which files were selected (in sql), and when the page is loaded fill in the checkboxes based on stored data.   I'll give your on-click approach a try and see if I can make loading more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do?

You are creating a huge page and asking how to make it consume less memory? That's obvious – don't show all the tree in the page, it's never going to be useful to any user anyway.

You can limit the output to only several levels, for example.

Comment: Well the context of this application is a SMB backup utility a-la veritas, only running over HTTP with a windows service as back-end.   I want the enumerated files and directories to be selectable as backup targets.   I can do this dynamically as the user traverses through the directories, but it still makes me nervous that if the user expands enough of the directory trees it will still make the webbrowser spiral out of control memory-wise.